# autofs : dynamic mounting rule for s3 bucket

Tags: fuse, autofs, file-server, amazon-s3

I successfully implement autofs to automatically mount s3 bucket to the server which running ubuntu server 14.04.5 by following [this tutorials](https://sites.google.com/site/hollyroyaltea/home/filesystem/s3fs). but the number of bucket (that needs to automatically mounted) is dynamic, means its can be increase or decrease. so far I need to add/remove rule in autofs config whenever the bucket number changed.

the option command for mount those bucket is same. only path and bucket name that have difference. here is my configuration :
on /etc/auto.master

```
+auto.master
/- /etc/auto.s3bucket --timeout=30
```

on /etc/auto.s3bucket

```
[mount-point-bucket1] -fstype=fuse,uid,gid,etc,etc  :[tool-mounting]#bucket1
[mount-point-bucket2] -fstype=fuse,uid,gid,etc,etc  :[tool-mounting]#bucket2
.....
[mount-point-bucketX] -fstype=fuse,uid,gid,etc,etc  :[tool-mounting]#bucketX
```

my question : Is there a built-in script or function in autofs to dynamically add or remove rule in the file configuration?. so I don't need to re-config whenever the bucket is decrease or increase.

Answer (score 1):

first check your S3 access:

```
s3fs your-s3-bucket /mnt -o passwd_file=/path/to/your/secrets
```

if this works, enter this into your autofs config:

```
s3 / -fstype=fuse,passwd_file=/path/to/your/secrets :s3fs\#your-s3-bucket
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your guide and did this for a non-amazon host: `s3fs publicdrive /home/mini/clould -o passwd_file=\`pwd\`/secret -o allow_other -o host=https://non-amazon-host` and it worked so nice

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but needed some info on doing this so stumbled across this. I kept getting a syntax error using the answer previously proposed. I had to adjust my `auto.master` and add a url to my map file since our corp site is using on-prem AWS. I'll leave my notes here in case it helps anyone out.

**auto.master**

```
/-    /etc/auto.s3fs --timeout=30,--ghost
```

**auto.s3fs**

```
# note: mkdir /mnt/my_s3_bucket and chmod/own root 0600 /etc/s3fs/secrets
/mnt/my_s3_bucket/ -fstype=fuse,passwd_file=/etc/s3fs/secrets,url=https://s3.mycorp.com :s3fs\#my-s3-bucket
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically mount a bucket set your /etc/auto.s3bucket to:

`* -fstype=fuse,uid,gid,etc,etc :[tool-mounting]#&`

Comment: We prefer answers that include a bit more explanation.